# Navigating between pages - Expression Blend

Tags: c#, xaml, expression-blend

I have used an event handler for Page navigation and the code I have used is:

```
private void Menu(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Content=new Page1();
}
```

Using this it is possible to navigate from `MainWindow.xaml` (Itemtype - Window) to `Page1.xaml` (Itemtype - Page).

Now in `Page1` there is a button, and when I click on this, it should navigate to another page, say Page 2. But when I use the above method to navigate from `Page1` to `Page2`, it doesn't work.

Is it possible to use event handlers in this case, do I need to make any modifications in the code?